# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 578 did not have 8 elements

Tags: r, element

I receive this error:

> Reading Keyboard data: d:\tpr-db\TT03\Tables\P06_T1 .kd Error in
>   scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
>   line 578 did not have 8 elements

When I open the file in question, however, line 578 does seem to have 8 elements. That is, line 578 does not look any different than lines 577 or 579 with regards to number of elements?

I have run the exact same script with other data tables with no problems what so ever, so the problem should be in the data file and not in the script itself.

Data:

```
   KDid Time    Type    Cursor  Char    TTseg   STid    TTid
    0   36910   Mins    0   D   1   1   1
    1   37128   Mins    1   e   1   1   1
    ...    
    576 326214  Mins    416 h   3   77  83    
    577 326541  Mins    417 y   3   77  83
    578 326900  Mins    418 \   3   77  83
```

Any tips and advice would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: try adding `allowEscapes=F` to your `scan` call. The backslash in R is treated as an escape.

Comment: Or try `fill = TRUE`...